# error: no matching function for call to / candidates are

Tags: c++, message

I been trying to fix this code but I keep getting the same errors. Im not exactly sure how to fix and I was hoping maybe someone here might be able to. The compiler message is :

> no matching function for call to `Date::Date(int)'
>
> note candidates are: Date::Date(const Date&)
>
> note                 Date::Date(int, int, int)
>
> note                 Date::Date()

Here is the the main file:

```
/*-------------------- Lab7.cpp ------------------*/
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Employee.h"
using namespace std;

int main ( )
{
Employee emp1;
emp1.printPInfo( );

Employee emp2("John", "Doe", 111111, Date((10,25,1990)),
         Date((11, 15, 2010)), 750.00);
emp2.printPInfo( );

Employee emp3;
emp3.readPInfo( );
emp3.printPInfo( );

Employee emp4("Peter", "Parker", 222222, Date((8, 12, 1985)),
         Date((11, 32, 2114)), 800.00);
return 0;
}
```

Here is the Employee.h file that is include in the main file:

```
/*-------------------- Employee.h ---------------*/
#include <string>
#include "Date.h"
using std::string;

class Employee
{
      public:
      Employee( );
      Employee(string fName, string lName, int id,
               Date &bday, Date &hday, double bpay);
      void readPInfo( );
      void readPayInfo( );
      void printPInfo( );
      double getBpay( );
      double getGpay( );
      double computeTax( );
      void printPayInfo( );
      private:
      string firstName, lastName;
      int idNum;
      Date birthDay;
      Date dateHired;
      double basePay;
};
```

And lastly the Date.h file included in Employee.h

```
/*-------------------- Date.h --------------------*/
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H
class Date
{   
    public:
    Date(int m = 1, int d = 1, int y = 1);
    void inputDate( );
    void outputDate( );
    int getMonth( ), getDay( ), getYear( );
    private:
    int month, day, year;
    void checkDate( );
};
#endif
```

Lastly, here are both of the cpp files for the header files above:

```
/*------------------- Date.cpp -------------------------*/
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Date.h"
using namespace std;

Date:: Date( int m, int d, int y)
{
 month = m;
 day = d;
 year = y;
 checkDate( );
}

void Date:: checkDate( )
{
int m, d, y;
m = getMonth( );
d = getDay( );
y = getYear( );

static int daysofmonth[12]= {31, 28, 30, 31,
                          30, 31, 30, 31, 
                          30, 31, 30, 31};

if ( m < 1 || m >12)
    cout << "\nInvalid Month.";
    exit(1);
if (d < 1 || d > daysofmonth[m - 1])
    cout << "\nInvalid Day.";
    exit(2);
if (y < 1960 || y > 2013)
    cout << "\nInvalid Year.";
    exit(3);
}

void Date:: inputDate( )
{
 cin >> month >> day >> year;
 checkDate( );
}

void Date:: outputDate( )
{
 cout << getMonth( ) << "/" 
      << getDay( ) << "/" << getYear( );
}

int Date:: getMonth( )
{
 return (month);
}

int Date:: getDay( )
{
return (day);
}
int Date:: getYear( )
{
return (year);
}

/*------------------ Employee.cpp ---------------*/
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Employee.h"
using namespace std;

/*----------------- constructors ----------------*/
Employee ::Employee( ): idNum(999999),
                        dateHired(Date(1, 1, 2013))
{
basePay = 0.00;
}

Employee ::Employee(string fname, string lname,
         int id, Date &bday, Date &hday, double bpay)
{
     firstName = fname;
     lastName = lname;
     idNum = id;
     birthDay = bday;
     dateHired = hday;
     basePay = bpay;    
}
/*-------------- Member Functions ---------------*/

void Employee :: readPInfo( )
{
     cin >> firstName >> lastName >> idNum;
     birthDay.inputDate( );
     dateHired.inputDate( );
}

void Employee :: readPayInfo( )
{
     cin >> basePay;
}
void Employee :: printPInfo( )
{
     cout << setw(10) << "Name:\t" << lastName
          << ", " << firstName << endl;
     cout << setw(10) << "ID:\t" << idNum << endl;
     cout << setw(10) << "DOB:\t";
     birthDay.outputDate( );
     cout << endl << setw(10) << "BOH:\t";
     dateHired.outputDate( );
     cout << endl;
}

double Employee :: getBpay( )
{
     return(basePay);
}

double Employee :: computeTax( )
{
     double taxDeduct, gross;
     gross = getGpay( );

     if(gross > 1000) taxDeduct = gross * .20;
     else if(gross >= 800) taxDeduct = gross * .18;
     else if(gross >= 600) taxDeduct = gross * .15;
     else taxDeduct = gross *.10;

     return(taxDeduct);
}

void Employee :: printPayInfo( )
{
     double gross, tax;
     gross = getGpay( );
     tax = computeTax( );
     cout << "\nTax Deduction:\t$" << tax;
     cout << "\nNetPay:\t$" << gross - tax;
}
```

The error points two lines which are:

```
Employee emp2("John", "Doe", 111111, (Date(10,25,1990)),(Date(11, 15, 2010)), 750.00);
Employee emp4("Peter", "Parker", 222222, (Date(8, 12, 1985)),(Date(11, 32, 2114)), 800.00);
```

Any ideas as to what is wrong?

Comment: The error message doesn't correspond to your code. Is it possible that you didn't actually save `date.h`, or your compiler is looking at an old version of `date.h` ? (Try inserting a `#error foo` into `date.h` and see if this causes compilation to break)

Answer (score 2):

Calls like

```
Date((11, 15, 2010))
```

is probably the culprit. Instead of passing three ints to the date constructor, the inner parentheses made it pass a single parameter whose value is the value of the expression `11, 15, 2010`. The comma gets interpreted as the comma operator, which evaluates the first and second operands, discard the value of the first, and returns the second.

Use `Date(11, 15, 2010)` and you should be fine.

EDIT: Note that if you are passing a temporary, your `Employee` constructor must take them by `const` reference (which it should anyway since it's just storing a copy and not modifying the `Date` object in any way).

Answer (score 0):

The comma operator evaluates its first arguments, throws the result away, and returns the result of the second.

Like this:

```
int x = 1,2,3;
```

after which, `x` is 3.

You're writing

```
Date((11, 32, 2114))
```

where, since you added a couple of brackets, the argument (*not* arguments) to `Date` is `(11, 32,2114)`, which is a single `int` - `2114` - because you're using the comma operator.

Change it to

```
    Date(11, 32, 2114)
```

But the error message does not correspond to the lines you say it does.
The error message you get from those is along the lines of "cannot bind a non-const reference to a temporary", and that's because of the constructor's `Date` parameters, which are non-const references.

Either make them const references, but do it consistently:

```
Employee(const string& fName, const string& lName, int id,
         const Date &bday, const Date &hday, double bpay);
```

or just forget about passing references (it's an overrated practice):

```
Employee(string fName, string lName, int id,
         Date bday, Date hday, double bpay);
```